# Configuration of chiral center in cocaine

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality, erratum

[image]

I couldn't get the absolute configuration for the chiral center I marked. I got *R*, but according to my answer key it is apparently *S*. Would really appreciate an explanation.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that answer keys occasionally have mistakes. Note that the chirality where the benzoate group is attached has the $S$ configuration, as does the bridgehead chirality center to the front. It is possible that if this was an assignment or exam question, your instructor previously gave cocaine with a different chirality center marked on an older version and forgot to update the key for the different chirality center.

Answer (score 12):

You are actually right, that stereocenter does have *R* stereochemistry. The four substituents to the chiral center in question are:

- 1 - $\ce{CO(O)}$ = $\ce{C(O)3}$
- 2 - $\ce{C(O)(C)(H)}$
- 3 - $\ce{C(N)(C)(H)}$
- 4 - $\ce{H}$

These are ranked and numbered according to the [Cahn-Ingold-Prelog priority rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Ingold%E2%80%93Prelog_priority_rules). Adding the numbering to the structure:

[image]

Orienting the lowest priority group away from us and following the direction of the numbering, we confirm that it does indeed have *R* stereochemistry:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.10194104.html?rid=bc85295c-5fe0-48ec-b666-1b3b116c0d95) returns the following name when searching for *cocaine:*

> (1*R*,2*R*,3*S*,5*S*)-2-Methoxycarbonyltropan-3-yl benzoate

And the following image:

> [image: structure of (–)-cocaine]

The structure is identical to the one given in your assignment and the carbon in question is position 2. The name gives carbon 2 as *R*-configured.

This answer was meant to supplement ringo’s answer which shows how to derive the correct CIP priorities which clearly give *R* as well.